# python from c++ in visual studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I used the visual studio installer to install python and could run the basic python program.
Now I want to make a new c++ console program and call the python script from there.

When googling I saw I need to include the "Python.h" in my c++ function. I tried to include and i get the message  "cannot open the source file" . Is it because I used visual studio to install the python. And most of googling have installed python separately.

Comment: Im using Visual studio 2019 and used the VS installer to get python. So there is anyway way Visual studio allows us to link c++ and python ?

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of visual studio, just installed python interpretter. So installed Visual studio 2019 and had a option to select Python3

With that option , it created a new directory, C:\Python27amd64\

Now I created a new console application:
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "C:\Python27amd64\include\Python.h"

    int main()
    {
        Py_Initialize();
        PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
         "print('Today is',ctime(time()))\n");
        //std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }
```

And also followed the following steps :

1. Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories. I added the "C:\Python27amd64\include"
   2.Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories. : I added C:\Python27amd64\libs
   3.Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies: I added python27.lib
2. I changed the build to "Release x64". Because it couldnot find the debug libraries